# Derive Christoffel Symbols for FRW

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor

In Weinberg's Cosmology, the FRW metric is
\begin{equation}
 d\tau^2=dt^2-a^2\left[d\vec{x}^2+K\dfrac{(\vec{x}\cdot d\vec{x})^2}{1-K\vec{x}^2}\right]
\end{equation}
with $g_{ij}=a^2\left(\delta_{ij}+K\dfrac{x^ix^j}{1-K\vec{x}^2}\right)$. From this, the final Christoffel symbol is
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^i_{jl}=K\widetilde{g}_{jl}x^i=\widetilde{\Gamma}^i_{jl}
\end{equation}
with $\tilde{g}_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+K\dfrac{x^ix^j}{1-K\vec{x}^2}$. I tried calculating it with
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^i_{jl}=\frac{1}{2}\tilde{g}^{im}\left(\tilde{g}_{jm,l}+\tilde{g}_{lm,j}-\tilde{g}_{jl,m}\right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\tilde{g}_{jm,l}=\dfrac{K}{(1-K\vec{x}^2)^2}\left[(1-K\vec{x}^2)(\delta_{jl}x^m+\delta_{ml}x^j)+2Kx^jx^mx^l\right]
\end{equation}
with permutation of indices. I got
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^i_{jl}=\dfrac{K\tilde{g}^{im}}{1-K\vec{x}^2}\left(\delta_{jl}+K\dfrac{x^jx^l}{1-K\vec{x}^2}\right)x^m=\dfrac{K\tilde{g}^{im}\tilde{g}_{jl}x^m}{1-K\vec{x}^2}.
\end{equation}
What's bothering me is the denominator. Can anyone point out my error? Or can anyone show how to derive this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. We use
\begin{equation}
\tilde{g}^{im}=\delta^{im}-Kx^ix^m
\end{equation}
and get
\begin{align}
\Gamma^i_{jl}&=\dfrac{K(\delta^{im}-Kx^ix^m)\tilde{g}_{jl}x^m}{1-K\vec{x}^2}\\
&=\dfrac{K(1-K\vec{x}^2)\tilde{g}_{jl}x^i}{1-K\vec{x}^2}\\
&=K\tilde{g}_{jl}x^i.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Did you compute $\tilde g^{im}$? That is a non-trivial calculation and may account for the extra factor.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. Thanks!